# Truncation of fractions

Tags: filters, discrete-signals, filter-design

I am working on IIR filter design, I got filter coefficients, now I want to truncate the coefficients so as to perform scaling.

let 0.2145678340000 be one of my coefficients. I want to truncate to 0.21456

I used below code to do that, but it wont work.

```
x_tr = fix(x*2^5)/2^5
```

can someone help me

thanks

Comment: "truncate the coefficients so as to perform scaling": um, scaling and truncating are different things; what is it that you want to do?

Comment: $ x_tr = fix(x*10^5)/(10^5)$ if you want truncate to 5 digits, you need to us a base-10 scale factor, not base 2. Base-2 truncates to 5 bits, not 5 digits

Comment: Be very careful about truncating IIR filter coefficients as the effect on the frequency response can be substantial (Be sure to review the before/after response)

Comment: 1. Hi Marcus, I am working on reduced adder graph algorithm, in order to scale my coefficients first I need to truncate so that my coefficients are in look up table.